# NSMenu with 2 standard + variable number of NSMenuItems

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmenuitem, nsmenu

I have an `NSMenu` with 2 default items (at the top of it).

Then the rest of the menu will be populated.

What I want is to "save" the state of the initial menu (with the two items in it), and add items to that (original) menu; and not just keep adding and adding.

So, if I have to add other items, those will have to be added in the initial menu.

> **Example :**
>
> - Menu At the beginning : A B |
> - Menu After User does This : A B | C D E
> - Menu After User does That : A B | G H I J K
> - etc

How should I go about that? *(I tried "saving" the initial menu, and then "copying" that to the current menu, so that I could add items on top of it, but it didn't work... :-S)*

---

```
[DOC_UI setCurrentMenu:[[DOC_UI originalMenu] copy]];

// I'm adding the items here

for (NSMenuItem* mi in [[DOC_UI currentMenu] itemArray])
      NSLog(@"orig :: mi : %@",[mi title]);

/* The weird thing is that the items ARE NSlogged, but the change is NOT reflected. */
/* (When I was just adding to the existing items, the items did show up...) */
```

Comment: It is a bit confusing to what you are wanting to do!. (or I am being thick) Can you elaborate a bit better, and what is setCurrentMenu:??. Ar you talking about submenus or menuitems like file,edit, view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about menu items of a menu, you can remove all but the first 2 items in a loop when you want to go back to your original menu. If you have a menu with 2 default items called userMenu, just do this:

```
-(void)removeMenuItems {
for (NSInteger i=self.userMenu.itemArray.count - 1; i>1; i--) {
    [self.userMenu removeItemAtIndex:i];
}
```

}

Comment: I've thought of that (quite obvious) solution already... and yep, it's fixed! Thanks a lot anyway! ;-)